# KendoUI AutoComplete show cross icon with selected text

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-autocomplete

Is it possible to configure the selected option from KeondoUI Autocomplete? I am looking forward to display the text with an cross icon, so when the user clicks on cross the value is removed from the autocomplete box. The code below from schema is shown as html inside the textbox, and I am unable to parse it.

[image]

Code for reference:

```
        $("#txtSearch").kendoAutoComplete({
            template: '<span class="hide">#: data.Value #</span><span>#:     data.Text #    </span>',
            dataTextField: "Name",
            filter: "contains",
            minLength: 3,
            placeholder: "Find User",
            separator: ", ",
            noDataTemplate: 'No user found',
            dataSource: dataSourceForUser,
            select: onSelectUser
        });

        function onSelectUser(e) {        
            selectedAttendees.push({
                Value: e.item["0"].childNodes["0"].outerText,
                Text: e.item["0"].childNodes["1"].outerText,
                AdditionData: e.item["0"].childNodes["2"].outerText
            });

            console.log(selectedAttendees);
        }

        var dataSourceForUser = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            type: "json",
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "someUserFilter",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json"
                },
                parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                    if (operation === "read") {
                        return { content: options.filter.filters["0"].value };
                    }
                }
            },
            schema: {
                parse: function (response) {
                    var length = response.length;
                    var dataItem;
                    var idx = 0;

                    for (; idx < length; idx++) {
                        dataItem = response[idx];
                        dataItem.Name = '<span style=\'border:1px solid red;\'>' + dataItem.Text + '</span>';
                    }

                    return response;
                }
            }
        });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: kendo ui autocomplete or multiselect? you cannot select 2 item on kendo autocomplete. and the image you showed there similar to kendo multiselect on this page http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/index

Comment: @himawanraharja thanks for the response. Using separator I can add multiple items in AutoComplete, what I was looking forward to was "the cross feature" to remove selected options. MultiSelect works perfectly - without much change. Lack of KendoUI knowledge, thanks so much :-). I really appreciate your time.